# pyspark `readStream` not implemented error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, docker-compose

I launched a Spark instance in a Docker container. I then try to connect to it and read a web socket stream.

Here is the piece of code I use that throws the exception :

```py
def spark_ws():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.remote("sc://localhost:7077").getOrCreate()
    lines = spark.readStream.format("socket")\
        .option("host", "<my_ws_stream>")\
        .option("port", 443)\
        .load()
```

Note that I have **`pyspark` already installed** in my poetry environment.

I have the following error when trying to access properties on the `pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession` object :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/debian/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/scripts-CqDm9Ky7-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/session.py", line 466, in newSession
    raise NotImplementedError("readStream() is not implemented.")
NotImplementedError: readStream() is not implemented.
```

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.3.3
    container_name: spark-master
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 4040:4040
      - 7077:7077
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./src:/src

  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.3.3
    container_name: spark-worker
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=4G
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
      - ./src:/src
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem not long ago, I fixed it by checking if Java was installed. It wasn't so I installed it locally, problem was solved !

Comment: Could not find it in the docs, thanks mate.